# Is there a way to find out the total number of changes/edits it takes to convert a list of string values to a second list of string values?

Tags: python, string, list

I have two lists: list1 and list2(equal length) , consisting of string values of same length made from alphabets "a" to "o".

```
list1= ["gdmnbl","cfakdd","lkbhad",....]
list2= ["gamndl","bfakdd","lkbhad",....]
```

I need the output to be a list of total edits/changes need to convert a value from list1 to list2. **Example shown below:**

```
Taking into consideration the first value from list1 and list2 and comparing.
"gdmnbl" and "gamndl"

First character matches, so move on to next character.
Second character not a match, it takes 3 edits/changes to make "d" to "a". EXPLANATION:( "d" to "c", "c" to "b" and "b" to "a").
Third character, fourth character  are a match, so ignore.
Fifth character not a match, it takes 2 edits/changes to make "b" to "d". ("b" to c" and then "c" to "d".
Sixth character matches, so move on.

I want the output to be a list consisting of the sum of edits/changes. For the above example it is 3+2= 5.
```

So the output list should be like this:

```
list3=[5,1,0.....]
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?
Would greatly appreciate the help.
Thanks

Comment: I hope you might have tried something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to sum the distance between the characters at the same position, you might do the following:

```
list3=[sum([abs(ord(i)-ord(j)) for i,j in zip(a,b)]) for a,b in zip(list1,list2)  ]
```

The `list1` and `list2` must have the same number of strings, and the string pairs must be of equal length.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
def get_diff(s1,s2):
    d = 0
    s1 = s1.lower()
    s2 = s2.lower()
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        d = d+abs(ord(s1[i])-ord(s2[i]))
    return d

list1= ["gdmnbl","cfakdd","lkbhad"]
list2= ["gamndl","bfakdd","lkbhad"]
final_out = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    d = get_diff(list1[i],list2[i])
    final_out.append(d)
print(final_out)
```